# How to create and save a csv file in media folder in django?

Tags: python, django

I am creating a csv file using HttpResponse in django and I also want to save it in the media folder. I have set the MEDIA_ROOT in settings.py

```
def to_csv(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=industry.csv'
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    data = Industry.objects.all()
    writer.writerow(['Name','Workplace and Designation','Contact No.','Email ID','Purpose of Visit','Self Employed Details'])
    for row in data:
        writer.writerow([row.name, row.wp_des, row.mobileno, row.email, row.purpose, row.semp_details])
    
    return response
```

It creates and downloads the csv file but I also want to save it in the media folder

Answer (score 0):

Use `settings`:

```
from django.conf import settings

writer = csv.writer(settings.MEDIA_ROOT / file)
```

Comment: it is giving me this error 'unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and '_io.TextIOWrapper'
'